# JS - Is there a kind of placeholder that I can use in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I would like to replace a part of my html code using `.replace()` on a variable value.

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace('value="SOMETHING"', 'value='+priceRounded);
```

I want to replace `value="SOMETHING"` by `'value='+priceRounded` whatever is `SOMETHING`. How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Wow. Why replacing entire body contents? Select the target `input` and change it's value instead!

Comment: I *highly* suggest taking a look at AngularJS / KnockoutJS and the sort

Comment: @Alex Just for replacing value of an attribute?

Comment: the value I need to change is like that- <script src=http:///url.com" someValue="??" someOtherValue="??"></script>

Comment: You can select the `script` elements using DOM APIs and change the attributes using `setAttribute` method. Replacing entire contents of the document just for replacing value of an attribute is a terrible idea!

Comment: @clementr rather instead of replacing create the whole new string using JS variables and put it in body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you know which tag you want to replace this might be the easiest solution.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for(c=0;c<elems.length;c++) {
   if(elems[c].getAttribute('value') === 'SOMETHING') {
      elems[c].setAttribute('value','something something');
      elems[c].setAttribute('value2','something something again');
   }
}
```

If you don't know the tag name you can use

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('*[value]')
for(c=0;c<elems.length;c++) {
   if(elems[c].getAttribute('value') === 'SOMETHING') {
       elems[c].setAttribute('value','something something');
       elems[c].setAttribute('value2','something something again');
   }
}
```

```js
function run() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('*[value]')
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var div;
    for(c=0;c<elems.length;c++) {
       div = document.createElement('div');
       div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Found '+(typeof elems[c]) + ' with value '+elems[c].getAttribute('value')));
       output.appendChild(div);
       if(elems[c].value == 'SOMETHING') {
           elems[c].value ='blablabla bla. the answer is 42';
       }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<input type="text" value="blah">
<input type="text">

<input type="text" value="whoa">

<input type="text">
<input type="button" onclick="run()">
```